# Snowflake - TABLE <table_name> command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am searching for official documentation of **TABLE** command(it is not the same as [TABLE(<string_literal>)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/literals-table.html)).

**Snowflake supports `TABLE <table_name>`**, which is a shorthand for `SELECT * FROM <table_name>`, but I am unable to locate its documentation. Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE t AS SELECT 1 AS col;

SELECT * FROM t;
-- COL 1

TABLE t;
-- COL 1
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=673132a8505a80aaa554f43804aae59b)**

It works with parametrized table name as well:

```
SET name = 't';

TABLE IDENTIFIER($name);
-- COL  1

TABLE TABLE($name);
-- error as TABLE() could be only used in FROM
```

I searched at [All Commands](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-all.html)/[Query Syntax](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs.html) without much success.

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation you're looking for is Table Literals:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/literals-table.html

Comment: No, I do not think  it is the the same construct, and I already put that link in my question

Comment: I guess it is supported due to compatibility with [Postgresql/ANSI SQL(?)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html)

Comment: Sorry, I re-read the question and tried the syntax. I'll see if I can find anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it right in your comment on another answer. It's the PostgreSQL [`TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-TABLE) command, not a Snowflake feature.

> `TABLE` Command
>
> The command
>
> ```
> TABLE name
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM name
> ```
>
> It can be used as a top-level command or as a space-saving syntax variant in parts of complex queries. Only the `WITH`, `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`, `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT`, `OFFSET`, `FETCH` and `FOR` locking clauses can be used with `TABLE`; the `WHERE` clause and any form of aggregation cannot be used.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it. But I would like to know full Snowflake capabilities and in which context it is correct to use it. The PostgreSQL version supports `TABLE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ]`. `ONLY` and `*` does not work in Snowflake. Second if it is a syntactic sugar and it is resolved to `SELECT * FROM` then `TABLE TABLE($name);` shouldn't end up with error

Comment: I see and I'm afraid I don't have more to offer. Nothing in the Snowflake docs stood out to me. The absence of documentation suggests that support for the command may be incidental, but I hope someone who knows better comes along with an answer for you.

Comment: No worries, it is actually very interesting, and I belive it deserves its own official documentation page. It is a nice shorthand after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking possible metadata. For the sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(col INT, col2 TEXT)
AS 
SELECT 1, 'a' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'b';
```

---

a) The output of queries is the same:

```
TABLE t;

SELECT * FROM t;
```

| COL | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

b) Query profile is also the same:

```
EXPLAIN USING TABULAR
TABLE t;

EXPLAIN USING TABULAR
SELECT * FROM t;
```

| step | id | parent | operation | objects | alias | expressions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | GlobalStats |  |  |  |
| 1 | 0 |  | Result |  |  | **T.COL, T.COL2** |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | TableScan | TEST.PUBLIC.T |  | COL, COL2 |

c) Query history - `TABLE t` has query type of `SELECT`:

```
SELECT QUERY_TEXT, QUERY_TYPE
FROM table(information_schema.query_history())
WHERE query_text ILIKE '%t;';
```

| QUERY_TEXT | QUERY_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| SELECT * FROM t; | **SELECT** |
| TABLE t; | **SELECT** |